# Program to check SSD health performance

Tags: gratis, hard-disk, hardware, ssd

I need an advice about what program should I use to check health and performance of SSD Drive. I bought some SSD Drives on outlet in a cheap price and now I would like to check them technically.
Ideally I want a software to be free but I can consider some reasonable fee off course.
What are Your recommendations?

Comment: First I would test if the SSDs are not fake, so a tool like "FakeFlashTest" or "h2testw" can write the full flash memory and check if it can save the data or drops them at a certain capacity. For monitoring use a tool that can read the S.M.A.R.T data of the drives, but note that SSDs can fail at any time without prior values you could indicate as warning. Best solution against failing drives are a recent backup.

Comment: This heavily lacks details. What manufacturer? What exactly do you want to check?

Comment: Manufacturer is SAMSUNG. I want to check for any bad blocks, storage capacity, the wear level and overall health status likewise some performance benchmark.

Comment: The health is monitored by SMART, part of the drive, and there is a windows tool called smartctl you have to download and run.   smartctl -a /dev/sda   (sdb,sdc,sdd,... as needed)  the "-a" is show all.